# Getting response from URL after changing config.json properties with Python

Tags: python, json, get, request

How can i resolve problem in Python?

1. Read config.json file located in :
   /data/python/config.json
   make a GET request to the URL under ‘url’ key and add the first 15 characters
   to a key name ‘content’ in the json file.
2. config.json:
   {"url": "https://www.google.com"}
3. config.json after code run:
   {"url": "https://www.google.com", "content": ""}
   Where  should be the first 15 characters from the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a site to ask people to write a code.

Next time asking a question, please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are to show your efforts and show the problems you encounter.

This is the code, that will help you to get what you want

> **Note:** you will need to install `requests` library before running the code. `pip install requests`

```
import json

import requests

with open("/data/python/config.json", "r") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

result = requests.get(config['url'])

config['content'] = result.text[:15]

with open("config.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(config, f)
```

It does simple things:

1. Loads `config.json` from json to python dict
2. Gets `url` value from it
3. Sends request using `requests` library
4. Adds content slice of length 15 to a dict with a key `content`
5. Saves updated dictionary to `config.json`

Comment: Thanks for you answer =)
Tried to run a code and got an error:
vitali@ubuntu:/home/Python$ ./test.py
./test.py: line 1: import: command not found
./test.py: line 3: import: command not found
./test.py: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 5: `with open("config.json", "r") as f:'

Comment: Are you running it with python?

Comment: yep.  In Visual Code with installed python extension. 
also tried with next syntax: 
vitali@ubuntu:/home/Python$ py test.py 
/usr/bin/py:16: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
  from collections import Iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py", line 167, in <module>
    result = eval(args.expression)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    test.py
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'py'

Comment: In RyCharm: - Error is different from Visual
C:\Users\Asturiel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Asturiel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asturiel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open("config.json", "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.json'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @Asturiel i have updated answer, so path now contains absolute path to "config.json" file

Comment: Very strange, i tried to run it localy and online (https://www.online-python.com) without success... Same problem!
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/python/config.json'


May be i neeed to install/import something else?

Comment: No, it just cant find where file is placed. Do you have "config.json" in /data/python/?

Comment: this is a problem. i cant find such folder in project folder. where from i take this file? I need to create it manually? data/python/ folder+config.json file(blank?)

Comment: You have `Read config.json file located in : /data/python/config.json` in your question, so i think you must create it here...

Comment: Ok. lets say it's working BUt what will be an answer to last question?
Where should be the first 15 characters from the response?